# This webpage is not available ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: google-chrome, dns, server, opera, mozilla

**Its happens only for http://www.sunflowercable.com/ and only my browser(mozilla,chrome,opera) other computer its working fine...  the complete error message is**

> The server at www.sunflowercable.com can't be found, because the DNS
>   lookup failed. DNS is the network service that translates a website's
>   name to its Internet address. This error is most often caused by
>   having no connection to the Internet or a misconfigured network. It
>   can also be caused by an unresponsive DNS server or a firewall
>   preventing Google Chrome from accessing the network. Access a cached
>   copy of http://www.sunflowercable.com/ Search on Google

Comment: If this website URL is working fine in another computer. Then, there must be the problem with DNS of your computer.